# Visual Studio 2010 - Message Box popping up twice, why and how to fix?

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I'm writing a small app that allows the user to return and update three types of labels based on searching by charting number, order number, or product ID. How the design works is that there is an input box where you input the either the charting number/order number/product id and specify by selecting one of three radio buttons corresponding to the above three choices for input. There are three boxes to the right of the input box that returns the label IDs of each type of label, and the contents of these box can be directly edited and updated by clicking on an update button. The problem is that the return message pops up twice after updating, which is a nuisance, so I was wondering where in my code should I change to resolve this issue? I will paste the full code below in case the problem is located somewhere I haven't expected:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim dbconn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim sql As String
    Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader

    Public Sub myConnection()

        dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Server=###;Database=###;Uid=###;Pwd=###;")
        Try
            dbconn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Connection Error: " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try


    End Sub

    Private Sub chartNoSub()

        myConnection()

        sql = "SELECT pltlbl, cuslbl, boxlbl from formats as a join ordtab as b join chart as c where a.prodid=b.cusled and concat(b.ordno, b.orditm)=concat(c.ord01, c.oitm01) and c.chart='" & inputBox.Text & "'"

        mycommand.Connection = dbconn
        mycommand.CommandText = sql

        mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader
        While (mydata.Read())
            pltLBL.Text = mydata.Item("pltlbl")
            cusLBL.Text = mydata.Item("cuslbl")
            boxLBL.Text = mydata.Item("boxlbl")
        End While

        mydata.Close()
        dbconn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ordNoSub()

        myConnection()

        sql = "SELECT pltlbl, cuslbl, boxlbl from formats as a join ordtab as b where a.prodid=b.cusled and concat(b.ordno, '-', b.orditm)='" & inputBox.Text & "'"

        mycommand.Connection = dbconn
        mycommand.CommandText = sql

        mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader
        While (mydata.Read())
            pltLBL.Text = mydata.Item("pltlbl")
            cusLBL.Text = mydata.Item("cuslbl")
            boxLBL.Text = mydata.Item("boxlbl")
        End While

        mydata.Close()
        dbconn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub prodIDsub()

        myConnection()

        sql = "select pltlbl, cuslbl, boxlbl from formats where prodid='" & inputBox.Text & "'"

        mycommand.Connection = dbconn
        mycommand.CommandText = sql

        mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader
        While (mydata.Read())
            pltLBL.Text = mydata.Item("pltlbl")
            cusLBL.Text = mydata.Item("cuslbl")
            boxLBL.Text = mydata.Item("boxlbl")
        End While

        mydata.Close()
        dbconn.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Input_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles inputBox.TextChanged

        pltLBL.Clear()
        cusLBL.Clear()
        boxLBL.Clear()

        If (inputBox.Text <> "" And prodID.Checked = False And ordNo.Checked = False And chart.Checked = False) Then MsgBox("Please select an option below before inputting.")

        If prodID.Checked = True Then
            prodIDsub()
        End If
        If ordNo.Checked = True Then
            ordNoSub()
        End If
        If chart.Checked = True Then
            chartNoSub()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub update_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles updateLBL.Click, updateLBL.Click

        myConnection()

        sql = "update formats as a inner join ordtab as b on a.prodid = b.cusled inner join chart as c on b.ordno=c.ord01 and b.orditm=c.oitm01 set a.pltlbl = '" & pltLBL.Text & "', a.cuslbl = '" & cusLBL.Text & "', a.boxlbl = '" & boxLBL.Text & "' where a.prodid = '" & inputBox.Text & "' or concat(b.ordno, '-', b.orditm)='" & inputBox.Text & "' or c.chart='" & inputBox.Text & "'"

        mycommand.Connection = dbconn
        mycommand.CommandText = sql
        mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim rows = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If rows <> 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Update successful!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Check input.")
        End If

        dbconn.Close()

    End Sub


    Private Sub clear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles clearLBL.Click

        prodID.Checked = False
        ordNo.Checked = False
        chart.Checked = False
        inputBox.Text() = ""

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Unrelated, but AFAIK `MsgBox` is VB6 legacy stuff in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. Consider replacing it with the more .net-idiomatic `MessageBox` class instead... which you're using elsewhere.

Comment: Also please see [mcve]. Questions asking "why isn't my code working?" should include a MCVE and a clear problem statement, not the whole entire code and why it was written.

Comment: `Private Sub update_Click(...) Handles updateLBL.Click, updateLBL.Click` - You've subscribed to your click event twice, so it'll run twice for one click. Change to just `... Handles updateLBL.Click`

Comment: What @GlorinOakenfoot said. How have you managed that? :) Also next question you don't need to copy _all_ of your code in. Just the _relevant_ code.

Comment: Whoa, good eye Glorin! This has been bothering me for weeks, but this worked perfectly! Thanks :D

Comment: Understood Jinx88909. I was just worried that what caused the issue was lurking somewhere I didn't expect, so I wanted to make sure I left no stone unturned haha..

Comment: @AmosWu makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this as answered;

The solution was found, somewhat incredibly, by @GlorinOakenfoot.

The `MsgBox` was being called in `Private Sub update_Click`, but the `Handles` had the event happening twice on every click, hence the recursion of everything.